# How do I prove that "If prime p does not divide natural number m, then gcd(p,m) = 1"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am having a problem with this.

If prime p does not divide natural number m, then gcd(p,m) = 1

I had to use this for my another proof and because I thought it was quite intuitive, I just assumed this is true and used it for my proof but then I was told that I have to prove it too. But the problem is I can't figure out how I should write a proof for this formally.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: One way to think about it: the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $p$ is in particular a divisor of both $m$ and $p$.  Since $p$ is prime, your only choices are $1$ and $p$, and it can't be $p$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

- By definition, the gcd of two numbers divides each of them.
- By definition, a number is prime iff the only numbers dividing it are $1$ and itself.

Do you see how to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

p is prime, p the set of divisors of p is {1,p}
1 divides ever number.  If p does not divide m, then only divisor they have is common is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof might be different depending on your definition of GCD.  The definition I prefer is the following: a GCD of two integers $m,p$ is a number $d$ which divides $m$ and $p$, and which has the property that if $e$ is an integer dividing $m$ and $p$, then $e$ divides $d$.  A GCD of two nonzero integers exists, is nonzero, and is unique up to sign, so it makes sense to say **the** GCD (that is, the positive one).

Since $d = \textrm{GCD}(m,p)$ is necessarily a divisor of $p$, your choices for $d$ are $1$ and $p$.  But also $d$ must divide $m$, so you cannot have $d = p$.  Therefore, the GCD is $1$.